# How can I see when a Heroku app was deleted?

Tags: heroku

One of our test apps got deleted recently. We're trying to track down how/why (suspicion is an error in an API call that we've made). Is there a way to get any logs from Heroku that shows who/when/how an app was deleted?

Comment: you can check it via your build logs from your dashboard.

Comment: The app has been deleted, so, I can't see build logs for it.

Comment: then i guess, it will not be easy to find out such logs.